# In Javascript initialize touch event without using touch start?

Tags: javascript

Touch start initialization has not been working in Mozilla and Mozilla based browsers in mobile. Is there any other way to achieve initializing touch events instead of `touchstart`?

For example:

```
box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]; 
  startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX); 
  starty = parseInt(touchobj.clientY); 
 }, false);
```

What can be done instead of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "rendered useless"? As far as I know, Firefox for desktop doesn't support touch at all, and the mobile version fully supports touchstart?

Comment: Do you mean Mozilla based browsers don't support `touchstart` event? I'd be quite surprised. Do you have any reference for what you mean?

Comment: You cannot initialize anything in touchstart. touchstart works alright but anything inside the function doesn't work apparently. Because I made a swipe event and in mozilla and adblocker browser for mobile isn't working.

Comment: @momar I am going to correct it. I meant firefox for mobile and most firefox based browsers like adblocker, etc.

Comment: @momar Sorry for the confusion.